# Limit of power series, 2 variables

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

In an assignment, I've run into the following problem.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \sum ^\infty_{n=3} \frac{n\cdot x^{n-2}\cdot(-1)^n\cdot(n-1)}{(2n)!}$$

I really hope someone can steer me the right way, thanks!

Comment: It seems your best course of action is to compute the value of the infinite sum, then compute the limit. Interchanging the limit with the sum would not be valid here.

Answer (score 2):

We have that

$$\cos x=\sum ^\infty_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{2n}}{(2n)!}\implies \cos \sqrt x=\sum ^\infty_{n=0} \frac{(-1)^n\cdot x^{n}}{(2n)!}$$

$$-\frac{\sin \sqrt x}{2\sqrt x}=\sum ^\infty_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^n\cdot n x^{n-1}}{(2n)!}$$

$$\frac{\sin \sqrt x-\sqrt x \cos \sqrt x}{4\sqrt {x^3}}=\sum ^\infty_{n=2} \frac{(-1)^n\cdot n (n-1)x^{n-2}}{(2n)!}$$

therefore

$$\sum ^\infty_{n=3} \frac{(-1)^n\cdot n (n-1)x^{n-2}}{(2n)!}=\frac{\sin \sqrt x-\sqrt x \cos \sqrt x}{4\sqrt {x^3}}-\frac1{12}$$

Comment: I have zero idea how you got there, but i appreciate it. Do you know of any videos / text sources where i can read up on this? Or could someone walk me through it? Mostly why does cos(x) equal the summation? And why does x^(n-2) become x^(2n)

Comment: We start with Taylor’s series for $\cos x$. Aren’t you aware about it? Then we have obtained the series for $\cos \sqrt x$ and by differentiation we have obtained the desired sum.

Comment: @Drax When you see a Taylor series with a factorial in the denominator, you might be reminded of $e^x, \sin x, \cos x,\ldots$. The fact it's alternating due to $(-1)^n$ should then remind you of $\sin x$ or $\cos x$. It's a good idea to have their series memorised and they're not too hard to remember. From there, it's just a matter of tweaking the already-known series to get to a closed form for the one you're given. To get there, you can use steps like substitution ($x\mapsto f(x)$), term-wise differentiation ($x^n\mapsto nx^{n-1}$), as **user** has done.

Comment: How would it be done, if x were to approach 0 instead of inf?

Comment: @Drax The same way. user showed that the infinite sum is equal to $\frac{\sin\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x}\cos\sqrt{x}}{4\sqrt{x^3}}-\frac{1}{12}$. For $x\to\infty$ the left fraction approaches $0$ so your limit is $-\frac{1}{12}$. For $x\to0$ the left fraction will approaches $\frac{1}{12}$ so your limit is $0$. You can use L'Hôpital's rule for the second limit.